# How to get driving distance between two addresses?

Tags: magento2

I want to get driving distance between two addresses. how can i achieve it using a web service that is completely free that do not charge after specific number of requests.As Distance Matrix API or Bing Map API etc starts charges for requests after specific number of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge, there is not any free API available into the marketplace which fulfill your requirement.

All the API do the same things, after some numbers of request they start there charges.

To get the different between 2 address, you need to do this things.

> 1. Get the destination address from the customer. where you save the source address already into the database.
> 2. Now Make the Call of the distance API which you are going to use.
> 3. Pass the source and destination addresses into the proper parameter format.
> 4. Now you will get the response from the API.
> 5. Now Do further things by checking response according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did you used any of Api to get driving distance between two addresses?

Comment: can you provide me any link or step by steps instructions that how can i use api in magento2 to get the driving distance

Comment: Yes, I am doing this one and tha why we have idea about this one.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can i achieve that?

Comment: I update the answer, kindly check that one and if that help please upvote and mark as solution, so that will help other in community.

Comment: which API you have used?? And did any Api have default keys for just developement purpose only

Comment: Can you please provide me the working code ?? how to make a Api and how to get responce ??

Comment: Can you ask the different question for new question about how to implement the API, so other community member also help you into this one.

Comment: Sure! thanks for assistance.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341755/how-to-implement-google-map-api-to-calculate-driving-distance-between-two-addres

Comment: Ok let me check that one, My above answer help you please upvote and mark as solution, so it will help other in community as well.