# How to implement Google Map Api to calculate Driving Distance between two addresses?

Tags: magento2, google-api

I have google map api key and i want to implement google map api to get driving distance between two addresses how can i

1. Make a call to distance api.
2. Pass the source and destination addresses into the proper parameter
   format.
3. Get the response from the API.

Comment: which API you are going to use?

Comment: i want to use Geo coding API.

Comment: Any API refrence link of that one?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview